# Is there any other way to evict keys aggresively with expired ttl in Redis

Tags: caching, redis, druid

My usecase: 
I am using Redis for storing high amount of data.
In 1 sec i write around 24k keys in redis with ttl as 30 minutes and i want the keys to be deleted after ttl has expired.
The current redis implementation of evicting keys is it works in tasks and each task pick 20 random keys and see if keys have expired ttl then it deletes those keys and redis recommends not more than 100 such tasks to be used. So if i se hz(no of tasks to 100) then Redis will be able to clear tke keys max @ 2000 keys/ sec which is too less for me as my insertion rate is very high which eventually results in out of memory exception when memory gets full.

Alternative i have is : 
1/ Hit Random Keys, or keys which we know have expired, this will initiate delete in Redis
2/ Set eviction policy when maxmemory is reached. This will aggressively delete redis keys, when max memory is reached.
3/ Set hz (Frequency), to some higher value. This will initiate more tasks for purging expired keys per sec.
1/ Doesn't seem feasible.
For 2/ & 3/
Based on the current cache timer of 30 minutes, and given insertion rate, we can use
maxmemory 12*1024*1024
maxmemory-samples 10
maxmemory-policy volatile-ttl
hz 100

But using 2 would mean all the time redis will be performing the deletion of keys and then insertion,as i am assuming in my case memory will always be equal to 12 GB

So is it good to use this strategy, or we should write our own keys eviction service over Redis?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Azure Redis cache? If yes, you can think of using clustering. You can have up to 10 shards in the cluster and this will help you to share your load for all different no. of keys for different operation.

Comment: No i have deployed the redis on Aws ec2 machine using standard redis installation steps

Comment: I am not sure why do you have such huge amount of data in Redis,say if it's your requirement then why do you need 30min TTL for each key. The easiest solution is to identify the key and it's required TTL as per your requirement. Redis can write it again in your cache if require but it can't do anything if you keep your memory full with idle Key

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to get a definitive answer to your question is to write a test. A synthetic test similar to your actual workload should not be hard to create and will let you know if redis can expire keys as quickly as you can insert them and what impact changing the `hz` value has on performance.

Using maxmemory should also be a workable strategy. Will mean the allocated memory might always be full, but should work.

Another is to reduce the number of keys you are writing to. If the keys you are writing to contain string values, you can instead write them into a redis hash field.

For example, if your inserts look something like this:

```
redis.set "aaa", value_a
redis.set "bbb", value_b
```

You could instead use a hash:

```
# current_second is just a timestamp in seconds
redis.hset current_second, "aaa", value_a
redis.hset current_second, "bbb", value_b
```

By writing to a hash with the current timestamp in its key and setting the TTL on the entire hash **redis only has to evict one key per second**.

Given some of the advantages of using hashes in redis, I expect the hash approach to perform best if your use case is compatible.

Might be worth testing before deciding.